# Get Conflict Value from ConflictWindow

Tags: arcobjects, esri-geodatabase, arcgis-desktop, versioning

When I reconcile a version in Arc Map, if it has any conflicts it will stop the reconcile operation and open a window. The window shows the conflicts of that particular version with red dots. My task is to read those values and generate a report which contains only conflict fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly its not possible.

See the code below

```
IVersionEdit4 = pVersionEdit4;
pVersionEdit4.Reconcile4("SDE.DEFAULT", true, false, false, false)
```

From that

```
IFeatureWorkspace commonAncestorFWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)pVersionEdit4.CommonAncestorVersion;
                IFeatureWorkspace preReconcileFWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)pVersionEdit4.PreReconcileVersion;
                IFeatureWorkspace reconcileFWorkspace = (IFeatureWorkspace)pVersionEdit4.ReconcileVersion;
                IEnumConflictClass pEnumConflictClass = pVersionEdit4.ConflictClasses;
                IConflictClass pConflictClass = null;
                //Loop through all conflict classes
                while ((pConflictClass = pEnumConflictClass.Next()) != null)
                {
                    IDataset pDataSet = pConflictClass as IDataset;
                    string datasetname = pDataSet.Name;
                    ISelectionSet pSelectionSet = pConflictClass.UpdateUpdates;
                    IFeatureClass featureClassPreReconcile = preReconcileFWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(datasetname);
                    IFeatureClass featureClassReconcile = reconcileFWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(datasetname);
                    IFeatureClass featureClassCommonAncestor = commonAncestorFWorkspace.OpenFeatureClass(datasetname);
                    IEnumIDs pEnumIds = pSelectionSet.IDs;
                    int oid =  - 1;
                    //Loop through all conflicting features. 
                    while ((oid = pEnumIds.Next()) != -1)
                    {
                        // Get conflict feature on the three reconcile versions.
                        IFeature featurePreReconcile = featureClassPreReconcile.GetFeature(oid);
                        IFeature featureReconcile = featureClassReconcile.GetFeature(oid);
                        IFeature featureCommonAncestor = featureClassCommonAncestor.GetFeature(oid);
                        //Loop through all fields of a conflict feature.
                        for (int intField = 0; intField < featurePreReconcile.Fields.FieldCount; intField++)
                        {
                            //Finding the conflict by checking two versions.
                            if (featurePreReconcile.get_Value(intField).ToString()!=featureReconcile.get_Value(intField).ToString())
                            {
                                //Writing to the Log.
                                base.LogReport(new string[] { WorkOrderName, featureClassPreReconcile.AliasName, oid.ToString(), featureReconcile.Fields.get_Field(intField).Name, featureReconcile.get_Value(intField).ToString(), featurePreReconcile.get_Value(intField).ToString(), featureReconcile.get_Value(intField).ToString(), featureCommonAncestor.get_Value(intField).ToString() });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

We will get the UID's of conflict classes. From that we should compare **PreReconcileVersion** and **ReconcileVersion** then we will get conflict field value.